# Files updated in git seemingly not updated in slug or on dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I've updated several files in the `public/assets/partials` directory of my Rails/Heroku application in Git. For example:

```
$ git remote show -n staging
* remote staging
  Fetch URL: git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git
  Push  URL: git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git

$ git diff staging/master~1..staging/master

diff --git a/public/assets/partials/feed.html b/public/assets/partials/feed.html
index 7161cc0..c8c03f0 100644
--- a/public/assets/partials/feed.html
+++ b/public/assets/partials/feed.html
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+<h1>some really obvious text</h1>
 <button ng-click="refresh()">refresh</button>
 <div class="poll-list">
   <article class="panel row" ng-repeat="poll in polls">
```

However, accessing this particular document through Rails does not show this change. I've also verified that the change is not present on the dyno:

```
$ heroku run cat ./public/assets/partials/feed.html --app myapp-staging
Running `cat ./public/assets/partials/feed.html` attached to terminal... up, run.6268
<button ng-click="refresh()">refresh</button>
<div class="poll-list"
  data-infinite-scroll="nextPage()"
  data-infinite-scroll-disabled="busy" >
  <article class="panel row" ng-repeat="poll in polls">
    <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>
    {{ poll.vote_count }} votes {{ poll.comment_count }} comments
    <a class="button" ui-sref="pollDetail({ pollId: poll.id })">Vote</a>
  </article>
</div>
```

All out of ideas. I don't think this is related to the asset pipeline since the files are stored directly in `public/` and the files don't seem to have been updated on the dyno's filesystem.

Comment: Any reason why you're putting partials in a folder other than `views`?

Comment: yes, they're client-side templates

Comment: Have you tried adding the folder specifically to git, using this command `git add ./public/assets/views` ?

Comment: The files (and changes) are checked into git, as you can see by the diff on the staging/master remote branch. I created and commited a new file in that public/assets/views folder, which was visible when I deployed to Heroku. Subsequent changes to the file did not appear on subsequent pushes. I suspect that the Heroku slug compiler is eagerly caching the ./public/assets directory.